# Dictionary key error despite the key existing

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm a bit at a loss. I'm initializing a dictionary inside a dictionary and it works all fine until I want to check the value defined inside a while statement.

There I'm getting a key error for "ScreenWidth".
My first attempts were to see if the variable has been accidently modified by writing the entire dictionary into a .txt file and then the subdictionary part itself that I access in the while.....all that works and gets me the results I expected but still inside the while I ge the key error.

Initialization:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.Data = {
            'Configuration': { 'MaxMapWidth':  256, 'MaxMapHeight': 256,
                               'TileWidth':   1216, 'TileHeight':   694,
                               'ScreenWidth': 1366, 'ScreenHeight': 768,
                               'MaxBiewDistance': 10 },
            'Map': {},
            'Tiles': {},
            'Player': {
                'Position': { 'MapName': None, 'X': 1, 'Y': 1, 'Direction': 0 }# in degree }

            }
        }
```

---

The method:

```
   def MyDo(self):
        f = open("e:\\test\\test.txt", "w")
        for key in self.Data:
            f.write(key + "\n")
            for subkey in self.Data[key]:
                f.write("    " + subkey + "\n")

                if ("Configuration" in key):
                    f.write("          " + str(self.Data[key][subkey]) + "\n");
        rayNumber = 0

        f.write(str(self.Data['Configuration']['ScreenWidth']))
        while (rayNumber < self.Data['Configuration']['Screenwidth']):
            #.... do my thing
            rayNumber = rayNumber + 1
```

The values inside the txt file:

```
Map
    Forest
Tiles
    tile003
    tile002
    tile001
    tile007
    tile006
    tile005
Configuration
    ScreenHeight
          768
    ScreenWidth
          1366
    MaxMapWidth
          256
    TileHeight
          694
    TileWidth
          1216
    MaxBiewDistance
          10
    MaxMapHeight
          256
Player
    Position
1366
```

Aside from the key error I would say it all works as intended. So my question here is what is causing this key error (especially as it all seems to be correct and the key existing)?

Comment: Might be because `'ScreenWidth' != 'Screenwidth'` (case-sensitive!). See the while loop line.

Comment: tnx overread it now for hours -.- I looked at all prnounciation,.... but not at case. tnx

Comment: btw would be nice to know why -1 (from what I saw the question is clear, that it is something as dumb as a case letter which was overlooked shouldn't award a - as far as I'm aware thus would be nice to know why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a *case* mistake -- look closely:

```
   f.write(str(self.Data['Configuration']['ScreenWidth']))
        while (rayNumber < self.Data['Configuration']['Screenwidth']):
```

The first time you spell with an uppercase W, the second time with a lowercase one. Those are two different, unrelated sub-keys.

Comment: That was it. I really hate when that happens.....looked at everything but the w/W. tnx will accept as soon as stackoverflow lets me

Comment: Case sensitivity is more often a bother than a help -- alas, the Python language is case sensitive, and so are most filesystems, and I detest that (I do miss the case-insensitivity of e.g Pascal, and Windows filesystems -- though I do not miss it quite enough to make me switch back to those technologies:-). At least for data structures you control, you might choose to make all keys lowercase, though.

Comment: I'm just used to camelcase as good as everything thanks to c#. Else I wouldn't bother in python (also windows user here^^)